# Sci-kit Learn KNN user-defined distance matric: mis-match between the actual value and the value passed

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, knn, nearest-neighbor

I am seeking your suggestions for a problem I have suddenly stumbled upon. I am using sci-kit nearest neighbor methods for finding the nearest neighbors. For calculating distance, I am using an user-defined distance function- looked like this:

```
def HVDM(a, b):
    print("a:", a[0], ",", a[1], ",", a[2], ",", a[3], ",", a[4], ",", a[5], ",", a[6], ",", a[7])
    print("b:", b[0], ",", b[1], ",", b[2], ",", b[3], ",", b[4], ",", b[5], ",", b[6], ",", b[7])
    return 0
```

To hold the data I am using pandas dataframe and numpy array. My dataset has eight attributes, that are being passed and the values of the first attribute are just 0,1 and 2. Below I have given some samples from my dataset:

```
[ 0.0 , 0.455 , 0.365 , 0.095 , 0.514 , 0.2245 , 0.10099999999999999 ,0.15] 
[ 0.0 , 0.35 , 0.265 , 0.09 , 0.2255 , 0.0995 , 0.0485 , 0.07 ] 
[ 1.0 , 0.53 , 0.42 , 0.135 , 0.677 , 0.2565 , 0.1415 , 0.21 ] 
[ 0.0 , 0.44 , 0.365 , 0.125 , 0.516 , 0.2155 , 0.114 , 0.155 ] 
[ 2.0 , 0.33 , 0.255 , 0.08 , 0.205 , 0.0895 , 0.0395 , 0.055 ]
```

Problem is when I tried to see, how these values are passed to the distance function, I have found some mismatch. Especially in case of the first passed parameter "a", where clearly the first attribute is changed but for the second parameter "b"- the first attribute is unchanged. Below I have given some passed samples:

```
a: [ 0.9554704333253531 , 0.5239920995930099 , 0.407881254488869 , 0.1395163993296614 , 0.82874215944458 , 0.35936748862820106 , 0.18059360785252604 , 0.23883085946851795 ]
b: [ 2.0 , 0.25 , 0.185 , 0.065 , 0.071 , 0.027000000000000003 , 0.0185 , 0.0225 ]
a: [ 0.9554704333253531 , 0.5239920995930099 , 0.407881254488869 , 0.1395163993296614 , 0.82874215944458 , 0.35936748862820106 , 0.18059360785252604 , 0.23883085946851795 ]
b: [ 2.0 , 0.2 , 0.145 , 0.05 , 0.036000000000000004 , 0.0125 , 0.008 , 0.011000000000000001 ]
a: [ 0.9554704333253531 , 0.5239920995930099 , 0.407881254488869 , 0.1395163993296614 , 0.82874215944458 , 0.35936748862820106 , 0.18059360785252604 , 0.23883085946851795 ]
b: [ 1.0 , 0.585 , 0.47 , 0.17 , 1.099 , 0.3975 , 0.2325 , 0.358 ]
```

Could anyone explain to me, what actually happening here?

Here is the important portion of code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

headers = ["sex", "length", "diameter", "height", "whole_weight",
           "shucked_weight", "viscera_weight", "shell_weight", "rings"]

df = pd.read_csv("abalone.data", header=None, names=headers, na_values="?")

replace_lebels = {"sex":     {"M": 0, "F": 1, "I":2}}
df.replace(replace_lebels, inplace=True)

def HVDM(a, b):
    print("a:", a[0], ",", a[1], ",", a[2], ",", a[3], ",", a[4], ",", a[5], ",", a[6], ",", a[7])
    print("b:", b[0], ",", b[1], ",", b[2], ",", b[3], ",", b[4], ",", b[5], ",", b[6], ",", b[7])
    return 0

X = np.array(df.drop(['rings'], 1))
y = np.array(df['rings'])

for item in X:
    print("X:", item[0], ",", item[1], ",", item[2], ",", item[3], ",", item[4], ",", item[5], ",", item[6], ",", item[7])

knn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=6, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='pyfunc', metric_params={"func":HVDM})
knn.fit(X)
```

Comment: can you include the actual code you are using?

Comment: @Yuca added, my whole code is slightly bigger, so I avoided that. But if you wish I can give you git link.

Comment: I have added a major portion of my code, excluding unrelated details. Output is same, Please check. @Yuca

Comment: but where's the code that generates the ill sex column?

Comment: a[0] or the first value from every row @yuca

Comment: I know, you have 4 blocks of code in your post, the third one shows what it seems to be the output for the calls to HVDM. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully certain about the behavior of NearestNegihbors ball_tree algorithm. So far what, I was able to understand that, the algorithm determines the values for "a". "b" represents the exact value you are passing from your data.

If you look carefully, you will observe that the value of "a" is always the same. I believe KNN set the same value for a to get the distance of the values "b". To get the distance KNN starts from a start point and compare all other points with that one. By doing that it determines which values are nearer.

In short, you are never setting the values of 'a'. You are giving the values of 'b'. The values of 'a' are determining by the KNN for getting the relative distance of your data points.